# Add affiliate tracker code to virtuemart thank you page

Tags: joomla, virtuemart, affiliate

I want to add an affiliate tracker code to my Joomla based website using VirtueMart. They told me to add the code on the thank you page but I couldn't figure it out. The VirtueMart version is 2.0.12 and the code is

```
<script src="http://network.clickbanner.gr/i_sale_third/10566/SALE_AMOUNT/TRANSACTION_ID
/OPTIONAL_INFORMATION&sale_status=P"></script>
<noscript><img src="http://network.clickbanner.gr/i_track_sale/10566/SALE_AMOUNT/TRANSACTION_ID
/OPTIONAL_INFORMATION&sale_status=P"></noscript>
```

Ι have to replace `SALE_AMOUNT` with the order's price excluding tax and the `transaction_id` with the order id. Any ideas how to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution:

The output of thank you page can be edited in /plugins/vmpayment/standard/standard.php (for standard payment method) or /plugins/vmpayment/paypal/paypal.php. Find the `$html` variable in `plgVmConfirmedOrder($cart, $order)` function and add the code you want after the line `$html .= '</table>' . "\n";` (line 135). In my case the code is:

```
$html .= '<script src="http://network.clickbanner.gr/i_sale_third/10566/'.$order['details']['BT']->order_subtotal.'/'.$order['details']['BT']->order_number.'
/OPTIONAL_INFORMATION&sale_status=P"></script><noscript><img src="http://network.clickbanner.gr/i_track_sale/10566/'.$order['details']['BT']->order_subtotal.'/'.$order['details']['BT']->order_number.'/OPTIONAL_INFORMATION&sale_status=P"></noscript>';
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this like,

```
First the order confirmation page of VM2.x is order_done.php 
the file you can find in the path : components/com_virtuemart/view/cart/tmpl/order_done.php
```

second thing.

The order placed in VM storing in the order table #__virtuemart_orders

```
with order id you can find all the amounts. with tax without tax etc.
(order_number,order_pass,order_total,order_subtotal,order_tax)
```

Comment: Is it right to add it there? I see that it calls $html which is in /plugins/vmpayment/standard/standard.php. I tried to add the script code at the $html before $html.='</table>' but then i get a 500 error in the page.

Comment: The Vm thank you page is order_done.php if u want to place the things any other place like shipping or payment section then you can find those in plugin path

Comment: I finally did it within standard.php file! The output shows up at the thank you page! When i go home i'll post here the solution. Thanks for your answers.